# How to place an order as guest in eBay Sandbox

Tags: paypal, ebay-api

Hi I'm trying to place an order on the Sandbox environment as a guest assuming that no Paypal account would be needed to be added for the guest. I'm using the below REST APIs in that order to get this done.

1. I have a Listing (published offer) with the id 1xxxxxxxxxx4 in sandbox
2. I called the Order API -> initiateGuestCheckoutSession (Item ID : v1|1xxxxxxxxxx4|0)
3. I called the Order API -> initiateGuestPayment with below request body

```
    {
    "paymentMethodType": "WALLET",
    "paymentMethodBrandType": "PAYPAL_CHECKOUT"
    }
```

Got this as part of the response

```
"providedPaymentInstrument": {
"paymentMethodType": "WALLET",
"paymentInstrumentReference": {
"externalReferenceId": "2QG41254DS871200X"
}
```

4. I called Order API -> placeGuestOrder (Session Id : v1|1xxxxxxxxxx4|123365312 )

```
    { "marketingTerms": [
    {"marketingTermsAccepted": false,
    "marketingTypes": [ "OFFER", "SURVEY", "PROMOTION" ],
    "marketingChannels": [ "EMAIL" ] } ]
    }
```

I'm getting below for response 400 Bad request

```
{
"errors": [
{
"errorId": 15004,
"domain": "API_ORDER",
"category": "REQUEST",
"message": "If this is a eBay member checkout, this error indicates that the buyer does not have a PayPal account linked to their eBay account. If this is a guest checkout, this indicates that the buyer's credit card information is missing. In both cases, submit the buyer's credit card information."
}
]
}
```

So I have these questions in mind.

1. Am I calling the right APIs, in the correct order? or am I missing
   something?
2. How do I add credit card information to this guest buyer?
3. If I'm to add credit card information to this guest buyer, are there
   any TEST Credit cards that could be used for this purpose?
4. If linking a TEST Paypal to this scenario how should it be done?
5. To avoid all this can't we set "Cash On Delivery" option for orders?
   if so how do you set that?

Thanks in advance, appreciate any help I could get on this matter guys.